# How do you pass a templated class instance as a template parameter to another template?

Tags: c++, templates, microcontroller, avr

I have a class template and I want to pass instances of it as a template parameter to anther class template. Such as:

```c++
typedef Pin<(uint16_t)&PORTB,0> B0;
typedef Pin<(uint16_t)&PORTB,1> B1;
```

Then I would like to pass them like:

```
Indicator<B0,B1> Ind1;
```

The pin class template that I'm using:

```c++
template <uint16_t tPort, uint8_t tBit>
class Pin
{
public:
    static constexpr uint16_t Port = tPort;
    static constexpr uint16_t DDR = tPort-1;
    static constexpr uint16_t PIn = tPort-2;
    static constexpr uint8_t Bit = tBit;

    static constexpr void  Toggle() 
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(Port) ^= (1<<Bit);
    }

    static constexpr void PullHigh() 
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(Port) |= (1<<Bit);
    }

    static constexpr void PullLow() 
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(Port) &= ~(1<<Bit);
    }

    static constexpr void SetOutput() 
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(DDR) &= ~(1<<Bit);
    }

    static constexpr void SetInput() 
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(DDR) |= (1<<Bit);
    }

    static constexpr void SetHighImpedance() 
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(Port) &= ~(1<<Bit);
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(DDR) &= ~(1<<Bit);
    }

    static constexpr bool Read() 
    {
        return (*reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(PIn) & (1<<Bit));
    }
};
```

I've been able to pass them to template functions. I assume template template arguments may be the answer. But have not been able to get it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non type template arguments are not limited to integers. You seem to pass a `uint16_t` only to reinterpret it as a pointer. Instead, you can pass the pointer itself as a template parameter.

Also, note that `reinterpret_cast` are not allowed in `constexpr` context.

Passing pointers at compile time would look like this:

```
template <uint16_t* tPort, uint8_t tBit>
class Pin
{
    // ...
};
```

It would be used like this:

```
using B1 = Pin<&PORTB, 1>;
```

Assuming you want to write the `Indicator` template class, it would simply look like this:

```
template<typename P1, typename P2>
struct Indicator {
    // ...
};
```

If you're concerned about enforcing `P1` and `P2` to be pins, it can be done by making a type trait and asserting on it:

```
// Base case
template<typename>
struct is_pin : std::false_type {};

// Case where the first parameter is a pin
template <uint16_t* tPort, uint8_t tBit>
struct is_pin<Pin<tPort, tBit>> : std::true_type {};
```

Then, use your asserts:

```
template<typename P1, typename P2>
struct Indicator {
    static_assert(is_pin<P1>::value && is_pin<P2>::value, "P1 and P2 must be pins");

    // ...
};
```

Then, to make a function that receive an `Indicator`, you can do the following:

```
// Pass type only, and use static members
template<typename IndicatorType>
void do_stuff() {
    IndicatorType::stuff();
}

// Pass an instance of the class
template<typename IndicatorType>
void do_stuff(IndicatorType indicator) {
    indicator.stuff();
}
```

These functions are invoked like this:

```
// Passing only the type
do_stuff<Indicator<B1, A1>>();

// Passing an instance
Indicator<B1, A1> indicator;

do_stuff(indicator);
```

This time I wouldn't be worried about `IndicatorType` not being an indicator. Any class that act as an indicator willl be accepted, and if cannot be used the same way as an indicator, then a compile-time error occurs. This will allow more flexibility about how indicators are implemented.

Also, I suggest you to read more, or more in depth tutorial about templates in C++. Sometimes overlooked, it's one of the most important and complex feature of C++.